# What's size or volume for Cooper pairs?

Tags: superconductivity

How to calculate the **size** for [Cooper pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooper_pair)?

Comment: *The electrons in a pair are not necessarily close together; because the interaction is long range, paired electrons may still be many hundreds of nanometers apart. This distance is usually greater than the average interelectron distance so that many Cooper pairs can occupy the same space.* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooper_pair

Comment: A Cooper pair is two electrons with equal & opposite momentum, so the size of the pair can't be constant.